# Emacs “shell-command-on-region” does not pass STDIN to command if command line contains meta-characters

Tags: windows, shell, emacs

I'm running Emacs on Windows-XP SP3
   GNU Emacs 22.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2008-09-07 on SOFT-MJASON

When I run a command where the argument contains shell meta-characters, my Emacs region is not passed to the command via STDIN as expected.  I've written a program to verify that this is the case:

```
## test.pl
my $lines = 0;
while (<STDIN>)
{
    ++$lines;
}

print "Input lines: $lines\n";

for (my $i = 0; $i < @ARGV; ++$i)
{
    print "$i: [[$ARGV[$i]]]\n";
}
```

For example, if the region contains:

```
a
b
```

And I run: `perl c:\bin\test.pl "<"`, I get:

```
Input lines: 0
0: [[<]]
```

If instead I run: `perl c:\bin\test.pl "-"`, I get:

```
Input lines: 2
0: [[-]]
```

My SHELL environment variable within Emacs is set to c:/emacs/bin/cmdproxy.exe

This has never been a problem until I started running a recent version of Emacs.  Does anyone know how to fix this? (I'm not interested in using any cygwin shell as my emacs shell)
**Edit:**
Any argument to test.pl I use that contains a shell meta-character has the same effect as using "<". For example passing "foo&" also results in "Input Lines: 0"

Similarly, any argument to test.pl I use that *does not* contain a shell meta-character has the same effect as using "-". For example passing "foo" also results in "Input Lines: 2"

Answer (score 0):

Using `<` indicates to the subprocess that you want to redirect from a named *file*, which Emacs is not supplying.  This is why you get 0 input lines.

Using `-` indicates to subprocess should expect input on `stdin`, which Emacs *is* supplying, and the shell is properly calculating 2 lines.

Comment: My Perl program does not interpret "<" and "-" in this way. Is there something else in the call chain that does? For example cmdproxy? Since these arguments are quoted, why would that be happening? Also, "<" can be replaced by anything containing a shell-metacharacter and the effect will be the same, for example "foo&" also gives "Input Lines: 0". And "-" can be replaced by anything *not* containing a shell meta-character and the effect will be the same, for example "foo" also gives "Input lines: 2"